# How to find the nature of elements in a quotient ring ,with ideal nonprincipal $\frac{\Bbb{Z}[X]}{(2,X)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory

while trying to find the nature of elements in the ring $\frac{\Bbb{Z}[X]}{(2, X)}$. I just put $X=0$, and $2=0$ so the all polynomials with even constant term belongs to the ideal $( X,2)$, and I am left with the elements of the form. $1+(X,2)$, I don't know whether it's correct or not. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Whenever you post a question on this platform, keep two things in mind, (1) Try to render your math equations using MathJax and (2) Show what have you done. This is not a place to get your homework done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost correct. You are just missing the trivial zero element.
A more straightforward way to see this is

$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(2,X)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(2)} = \mathbb{Z}_2 = \{\overline{0}, \overline{1}\}$$

**Edit:** In case you are confused about my first isomorphism $-$ you want to show $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, consider the homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\phi(f) = f(0)$. Find the kernel of this map, use the first isomoprhism theorem and fill in all the details to get the desired result.

So in our question, we have essentially written
$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(X,2)} = \frac{\mathbb{Z[X]}/(X)}{(2)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(2)} = \mathbb{Z}_2$$
which was how I got the first isomorphism.

**Edit 2:** In case you are wondering about the elements themselves of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,X)$; they basically are the equivalence classes of the constant polynomials $f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: Huh - I would perhaps like to know why this answer was downvoted?